# Installing Ubuntu with Win7 in Dual booting mode

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Toshiba satellite series laptop with win7 loaded. In the HDD there is a Un-partitioned space of 50gb, I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 on that un-partitioned space with dual booting mode.
Please help me how can I proceed.

Thank U

Answer (score 0):

- Boot ubuntu live-disk,select try ubuntu and install gparted by running the below command on terminal,

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Then open gparted,rightclick on the unallocated space and select *new* option to create new **ext4** partition.After that a **create new partition window** will appear.
- In that window change the filesystem to *ext4* and then select Add option(leave the other option as it is).After that click on *Apply*.

[image]

- Now run the ubuntu installer and select the *something else* option.Choose the created ext4 partition to install ubuntu.If the installer asks to create swap partition,give the swap partition size as double the RAM size.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to make partition .

Just start Installing it and when it asks for where to install choose **Something Else** and click on the un-partitioned free space and mention

1. Swap area as 2*x, as x is your physical ram, suppose you have 3 gbs of physical ram then make swap as 6 gigs or 3 gigs.
2. Rest make it root partition by mounting it as "/"

Both the partitions can be logical.

Hope it helped you.